# Prism Mvvm Mef Interactivity Open window new instance

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I'm in process of learning different Prism features and now I'm stuck on opening new window.
My application Shell has Master region and Detail region.
Shell's master region has DataGrid with items which when clicked show it's properties in Detail region.
What I need is a way to create new instance of window with double click on item in Master region.
And every new window can stay active until I close it, so I can open and other windows by clicking on any other item in Master region.

In the pre-MVVM-Prism times, I would probably do something like:

```
    ICollection<Window> MyWindows = new List<Window>();
    var wnd = MyWindows.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == id.ToString());
    if (wnd == null)
    {
        wnd = new MyWindow(this, id);
        MyWindows.Add(wnd);
    }
    wnd.Show();
```

But this is a no-go from Shell's ViewModel and Prism...

Had used something like InteractionRequestTrigger from my Shell xaml:

```
 <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CyberPopUpViewRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
    <prism:PopupWindowAction>
        <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <views:CyberPopUpView />
        </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
    </prism:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

But this allows me to create only single window.

Answer (score 2):

> But this is a no-go from Shell's ViewModel and Prism...

True, if you'd put the code directly in the view model. But it's completely fine if you put (read: hide) it in a service (that's injected as dependency and can be replaced with a mock when testing):

```cs
internal class WindowManager : IWindowManager
{
    public void CreateWindow( string id )
    {
        Window wnd;
        if (!_myWindows.TryGetValue( id, out wnd ))
        {
            wnd = new MyWindow( Application.Current.MainWindow, id );
            _myWindows[ id ] = wnd;
        }
        wnd.Show();
    }

    private Dictionary<string, Window> _myWindows = new Dictionary<string, Window>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will check this out as I did not thought of putting window creation in service. Is it possible that I define new Prism regions in the new layout in the new window?

Comment: I've never tried that, but it might work, I suppose.